# Proper use of rand()?

Tags: c++, random

So the idea with this is that it takes in the 9x9 array that's in main, and swaps around rows. It can only swap rows 1-3 with 1-3, 4-6 with 4-6 and 7-9 with 7-9. For some reason every once in awhile it will swap one from 4-6 with one from 7-9, and also sometimes it will give me absolute garbage for one of the rows 7-9. I've spent the better part of 2 hours trying to figure out the proper way to use rand() in this context and I am sure I am not doing it correctly. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void printSudoku(int square[9][9]) // Prints out the 9x9 array
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            cout << square[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void swapRows(int square[9][9]) // Randomly generates numbers, within bounds, and swaps those rows with each other
{
    int temp[1][9];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = (rand() % 2) + 0;
    int m = (rand() % 2) + 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        temp[0][i] = square[n][i];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        square[n][j] = square[m][j];
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
    {
        square[m][k] = temp[0][k];
    }
    int a = (rand() % 5) + 3;
    int b = (rand() % 5) + 3;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        temp[0][i] = square[a][i];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        square[a][j] = square[b][j];
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
    {
        square[b][k] = temp[0][k];
    }
    int c = (rand() % 8) + 6;
    int d = (rand() % 8) + 6;
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        temp[0][i] = square[c][i];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        square[c][j] = square[d][j];
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++)
    {
        square[d][k] = temp[0][k];
    }
}


int main() {
int square[9][9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
                    4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,
                    7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,
                    2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,
                    5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,
                    8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
                    3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,
                    6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,
                    9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,};
printSudoku(square);
swapRows(square);
cout << endl;
printSudoku(square);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: only call `srand` once.

Comment: I did only call it once..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`rand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand), it gives you a number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`.  When you use something like `rand() % 8`, it gives you a random number between 0 and 7.  This is more range than you want the random numbers to span.  You only want the random numbers to be from 0 through 2 (0, 1, or 2), then add the offset for the first row.

For example, `(rand() % 8) + 6` gives you a random number from 0+6=6 through 7+6=13.  Instead, use `(rand() % 3) + 6` to give you 0+6=6 through 2+6=8.

Comment: There are implementations of `rand()` in which the low-order bits are not very random. See question 13.16 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), or use something other than `rand()`. I believe C11 added random number support in the standard library.

Comment: C++11 did add a [`<random>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) standard library with more sophisticated random number generators that can be modified for use with common distributions.  If you are doing more serious work with random numbers, it is true that you should not use a linear congruential algorithm and take only the least significant bits (as with this modulo operator).  I felt that this level of detail was beyond the level of the OP and that there is learning potential in understanding the arithmetic of the technique originally attempted.